# using localStorage in Backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js, local-storage

I am putting together a backbone example in which models are created edited and deleted. I am able to save new models and edits to local storage, but am having a problem getting localstorage to properly display on refresh. It seems to be loading as a single object, and therefore gives me one model regardless of how many were added.

```
 var Thing = Backbone.Model.extend({
     defaults: {
         title: 'blank'
     }
 });
 var ThingView = Backbone.View.extend({
     template: _.template('<b><button id="remove">X</button> <b><button id="edit">Edit</button> <%= title %></b>'),
     editTemplate: _.template('<input class="name" value="<%= name %>" /><button id="save">Save</button>'),
     events: {
         "click #remove": "deleteItem",
         "click #edit": "editItem",
         "click #save": "saveItem",
     },
     deleteItem: function () {
         console.log('deleted');
         this.model.destroy();
         this.remove();
     },
     editItem: function () {
         console.log('editing');
         this.$el.html(this.editTemplate(this.model.toJSON()));
     },
     saveItem: function () {
         console.log('saved');
         editTitle = $('input.name').val();
         console.log(editTitle);
         this.model.save({
             title: editTitle
         });
         this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
     },
     render: function () {
         var attributes = this.model.toJSON();
         this.$el.append(this.template(attributes));
         return this;
     }
 });
 var ThingsList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
     model: Thing,
     localStorage: new Store("store-name"),
 });
 var storeVar = localStorage.getItem("store-name");
 console.log(storeVar);
 var thingsList = new ThingsList;
 thingsList.reset(storeVar);
 var ThingsListView = Backbone.View.extend({
     el: $('body'),
     events: {
         'click #add': 'insertItem',
     },
     initialize: function () {
         this.render();
         this.collection.on("add", this.renderThing, this);
     },
     insertItem: function (e) {
         newTitle = $('input').val();
         newThing = new Thing({
             title: newTitle
         });
         this.collection.add(newThing);
         newThing.save();
         console.log(this.collection.length);
     },
     render: function () {
         _.each(this.collection.models, function (items) {
             this.renderThing(items);
         }, this);
     },
     renderThing: function (items) {
         var thingView = new ThingView({
             model: items
         });
         this.$el.append(thingView.render().el);
     }
 });
 var thingsListView = new ThingsListView({
     collection: thingsList
 });
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var Thing = Backbone.Model.extend({
     defaults: {
         title: 'blank'
     }
 });
 var ThingView = Backbone.View.extend({
     template: _.template('<b><button id="remove">X</button> <b><button id="edit">Edit</button> <%= title %></b>'),
     editTemplate: _.template('<input class="name" value="<%= name %>" /><button id="save">Save</button>'),
     events: {
         "click #remove": "deleteItem",
         "click #edit": "editItem",
         "click #save": "saveItem",
     },
     deleteItem: function () {
         console.log('deleted');
         this.model.destroy();
         this.remove();
     },
     editItem: function () {
         console.log('editing');
         this.$el.html(this.editTemplate(this.model.toJSON()));
     },
     saveItem: function () {
         console.log('saved');
         editTitle = $('input.name').val();
         console.log(editTitle);
         this.model.save({
             title: editTitle
         });
         this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
     },
     render: function () {
         var attributes = this.model.toJSON();
         this.$el.append(this.template(attributes));
         return this;
     }
 });
 var ThingsList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
     model: Thing,
     localStorage: new Store("store-name"),
 });
 var storeVar = localStorage["store-name-7ee7d1e3-bbb7-b3e4-1fe8-124f76c2b64d"];
 console.log(storeVar);
 var thingsList = new ThingsList;
 //thingsList.reset(storeVar);
 var ThingsListView = Backbone.View.extend({
     el: $('body'),
     events: {
         'click #add': 'insertItem',
     },
     initialize: function () {
    thingsList.fetch();
    thingsList.toJSON();
         this.render();
         this.collection.on("add", this.renderThing, this);
     },
     insertItem: function (e) {
         newTitle = $('input').val();
         newThing = new Thing({
             title: newTitle
         });
         this.collection.add(newThing);
         newThing.save();
         console.log(this.collection.length);
     },
     render: function () {
         _.each(this.collection.models, function (items) {
             this.renderThing(items);
         }, this);
     },
     renderThing: function (items) {
         var thingView = new ThingView({
             model: items
         });
         this.$el.append(thingView.render().el);
     }
 });
 var thingsListView = new ThingsListView({
     collection: thingsList
 });
```

Comment: Could use a little commentary about what exactly you did here. Did you really just comment out that line and everything is happy now? Why did it work? What was wrong in the first place?

Answer (score 8):

You need to add the items to your collection, and then to read it in you need to call fetch. You also have a couple of extra trailing commas in your objects.

Here's a slightly modified version of your code which seems to work.

```
var Thing = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults:{
    title:'blank'
  }
 });

 var ThingView = Backbone.View.extend({
    //el: $('body'),
     template: _.template('<b><button id="remove">X</button> <b><button id="edit">Edit</button> <%= title %></b>'),
     editTemplate: _.template('<input class="name" value="<%= name %>" /><button id="save">Save</button>'),


    events: {
    "click #remove": "deleteItem",    
    "click #edit": "editItem",
    "click #save": "saveItem",
    },

    deleteItem: function(){
      console.log('deleted');

            this.model.destroy();
            //remove view from page
            this.remove();
    },

    editItem: function(){
     console.log('editing');
     this.$el.html(this.editTemplate(this.model.toJSON())); 
    },

    saveItem: function(){
     console.log('saved');
     editTitle = $('input.name').val();
     console.log(editTitle);
     this.model.save({title: editTitle});
     this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    },

    render: function(){
      var attributes = this.model.toJSON();
      this.$el.append(this.template(attributes));
      return this;
    }
 });

 var storeVar = localStorage.getItem("store-name");

 var ThingsList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
   model: Thing,
   localStorage: new Store("store-name")
});

 var things = [
  { title: "Macbook Air", price: 799 },
  { title: "Macbook Pro", price: 999 },
  { title: "The new iPad", price: 399 },
  { title: "Magic Mouse", price: 50 },
  { title: "Cinema Display", price: 799 }
];

console.log(things);

var thingsList = new ThingsList;

var ThingsListView = Backbone.View.extend({
   el: $('body'),

events: {
      'click #add': 'insertItem'
    },

initialize: function () {
    this.render();
    this.collection.on("add", this.renderThing, this);
    },


    insertItem: function(e){
      newTitle = $('input').val();
      newThing = new Thing({ title: newTitle });
      this.collection.add(newThing);
      newThing.save();
      //this.model.saveItem;
      console.log(this.collection.length);
    },


   render: function(){
     _.each(this.collection.models, function (items) {
            this.renderThing(items);
        }, this);
    },


  renderThing: function(items) {
    //console.log('added something');
    var thingView = new ThingView({ model: items }); 
        items.save();
    this.$el.append(thingView.render().el); 
  }

});

var thingsListView = new ThingsListView( {collection: thingsList} );
thingsList.fetch();
console.log(thingsList.toJSON());
thingsList.reset(things);
```

**Edit:** I see you are trying to read in the value stored in local storage under "store-name", the way backbone-localStorage works is that it uses the name of the store (in your case "Store-name") to store the ids of the rest of the models and then saves each model under a combination of the store name and the id, so say you had three models, you would end up with 4 entries in local storage,

```
  localStorage["store-name"]  //id1, id2, id3"
  localStorage["store-name-id1"] //model with id1
  localStorage["store-name-id2"] // model with id2
  localStorage["store-name-id3"] // model with id3
```

**EDIT 2**

Here's a link to a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ma7Pu/) of your code, to start I'm leaving the line `thingsList.fetch();` commented out, uncomment that line and comment out `thingsList.add(things);` and run it a second time and it should pull the models from local Storage (I left an alert in there).

Comment: Thanks for the response Jack. Unfortunately this does not seem to be working, in that nothing from localStorage displays on the page. Also I realized that I posted an earlier version of the app previously. I edited above and replaced it with the newer version, which saves to localStorage but does not correctly read from it.

Comment: I think your issue is that your are trying to read the data directly from localStorage incorrectly, I updated my answer with some more details.

Comment: thanks Jack, but this is still not working. When I change to  var storeVar = localStorage.getItem("store-name-id1");
 console.log(storeVar); It returns null. Is my syntax incorrect?

Comment: I was just using id1 to illustrate my point. The actual ids are based on the id's of the models or if there isn't one then backbone-localStorage will generate a random id (i think it's something like 12 characters). At any rate you can see what's stored in localStorage using most browser's debugging tools (for example on Chrome, Safari or Opera check under Resources/LocalStorage).

Comment: the object in the console looks like this: {"7ee7d1e3-bbb7-b3e4-1fe8-124f76c2b64d":{"title":"ggg","id":"7ee7d1e3-bbb7-b3e4-1fe8-124f76c2b64d"},... I get null with  var storeVar = localStorage["store-name-7ee7d1e3-bbb7-b3e4-1fe8-124f76c2b64d"];
 console.log(storeVar);

Comment: The well known todos example: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/examples/todos/index.html does what Im trying to do with regard to it's use of locaStorage. When I look at the code however, I am having a hard time figuring out which part is pulling the models from localStorage and how to apply it in my example.

Comment: In the above example collectionview has fetch statement in it's initialize function which fetch's the collection instance. I tried adding this to my example, but doesnt seem to work. I must be missing something.

Comment: Is there a reason you are trying to pull the models directly from localStorage instead of letting backbone take care of that? Assuming the models were saved the `fetch()` tells backbone to load it from localStorage. At any rate if you want to do it manually inspect the localStorage using one of the debugging tools (for example in chrome) and that should give you the correct key value that you need. I also added a jsfiddle to my answer.

Comment: No I am happy to let backbone handle pulling the models from localStorage. not clear on how. In the jsfiddle example you provided, any change to the model does not reload on page refresh. Also the alert is blank for me. And also that was an earlier version that I have since updated in my question. I do appreciate your help

Comment: The alert in the jsfiddle should be blank the first time you load, and after you comment and uncomment the lines that i mentioned in my anwser (i should have put that in the jsfiddle) it should show that it's a bunch of objects. I'll try and take a look at your updated code a bit later.

Comment: So I copied the code from the jsfiddle and did the comment changes. The alert shows [object Object], [object Object] so now I just need to figure out how to display the actual attributes of the objecst into the template.

Comment: The attributes are there, if you output it to the console instead of using an alert you should see them (I used an alert since I was doing it in a jsfiddle). I haven't had a chance to check out your code, but I think your template is fine and its just that your not hitting the render method. Try calling your collections render method on success of your fetch (you can pass in a callback, eg. `thingListView.fetch({ success: function( collection, response) { thingListView.render();}});`

Comment: I got it working. All I really did was to put  thingsList.fetch();
    thingsList.toJSON(); in the initialize function of ThingsListView. I could post the final example, but I want to credit you with the answer.

Comment: Also you can update your question with the working code on the bottom (leave the original code in case someone else comes across this post).